# Ссылка на профиль без GET параметров

Tags: .htaccess, php

Доброго времени суток!

Всё чаще в соц. сетях используют ссылки на профиля без GET параметров вида [vk.com/id1](http://vk.com/id1)
Так вот будет являться глубокой ошибкой то что по этой ссылке есть папка или файл. Я хотел бы узнать, это нужно прописывать в .htacces или же надо создать свою страницу 404 прописать в .htaccess страницу ошибки 404 404.php и там уже обрабатывать ссылку?

Answer (score 1):

> Так вот будет являться глубокой ошибкой то что по этой ссылке есть папка или файл.

Как правило, все ссылки в соцсетях динамические, либо возможное пересечение убивается ограничениями (в vk только администрация может выделить вам короткий идентификатор, поэтому сами вы на css или js не попадете). Файлов там, скорее всего, нет вообще (ну, кроме индекса), причем прямой запрос индекса можно заставить расценивать как запрос айдишника index.php.
В общем, папка сама по себе являться ошибкой не будет. Выдача пользователю айдишника, которая соответствует папке - вот это будет ошибкой. Но, вместе с тем, лучше перенести все файлы на поддомен, чтобы гарантированно избавиться от головной боли.

> Я хотел бы узнать, это нужно прописывать в .htacces

Вы пришли в очаровательный мир вебдева. Здесь есть много вещей, часть из которых плоха от рождения и поддерживается только за счет раздуваемой истерии, а часть просто пришла из древних времен и постепенно отмирает. Писать в .htaccess все подряд, кроме переброса на index.php или аналог - как раз такой рудимент. По-хорошему все запросы, кроме запросов пресловутых файлов, должны приходить в index.php (а если на доступ к файлам могут быть ограничения - тогда вообще все запросы должны приходить в index.php), и уже index.php должен разбирать, что и куда пришло, и выдавать ли вообще страницу 404. Делать отдельно 404.php - можно, конечно, но это такой же неверный ход, как и .htaccess: теперь логика приложения обрабатывается не только в index.php, но еще и в .htaccess, и в 404.php, что увеличивает затраты времени на поддержание.
**Long story short: ничего страшного не случится, каким бы из двух (трех) путей вы не пошли.** Но, на мой взгляд, вам нужно выбрасывать 404 внутри приложения (причем только там, где нужно - если папка js существует и из нее тянутся файлы, то не имеет смысла глушить ее 404, красивее будет поставить 403), разрешать конфликт папок и идентификаторов с противоположной стороны, и четко решить, что вы хотите сделать (потому что на самом деле у вас конфликт двух сущностей, а вам зачем-то нужна 404, которая прибьет **обе**).

И последнее замечание:

> Всё чаще в соц. сетях используют ссылки на профиля без GET параметров

И это правильно. Забудьте про .htaccess, забудьте про обычные GET-параметры: вы разрабатываете приложение, в котором все должно быть красиво и минимально зависеть от настроек сервера. Все это никуда не денется, но сервер должен быть настроен на запуск вашего приложения, урлы должны быть красивыми, и больше вас ничего не должно волновать, главное - не удобство технической реализации, а поставленная цель. GET-параметры - это прошлый век, не в том плане, что их запретили, а в том, что так уже не делают; они не исчезли, просто появились возможности делать более высокоуровневые и красивые штуки.

Простите за сумбур.

Comment: хмм.. Куда это делись GET параметры? вполне вероятно что в vk.com/id1 - ка раз GET параметр и есть id=1

Comment: ну тогда читаем что такое ЧПУ

Comment: @Ale_x, можно конечно после парсинга все позапихать в $\_GET, но сам источник данных все-таки REQUEST\_URI, а не GET-параметры

@bazaev05, вкратце происходит так: все запросы к вебсерверу перенаправляются на index.php. Пользователь запрашивает /крутоймачо777, а по факту загружается index.php. И уже index.php загружает приложение, которое смотрит, что же такое скрывается по адресу /крутоймачо777. Посмотрите mod_rewrite.

Comment: ну с таким рассуждением можно и по другому сказать - все параметры можно запихать в 1 и передать как GET - а в скрипте уже парсить - от этого суть не меняется -мы получаем параметры переданные в самом URL. 
а ЧПУ это сахарок не более того